# Can I use an OAuth2 access token to get an access token for a different client?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

In our project we want to have one "master" client the user has to get an access token for once. Any further clients that require an access token will do so through the "master" client.

Currently the user has to log in each time a client wants an access token. If our "master" client has a valid token and I try to get to the authorize endpoint with it, I either got forwarded to the login page or get an "InsufficientAuthenticationException: User must be authenticated with Spring Security before authorization can be completed."

At this point I wonder if it's even intended to access the authorize endpoint in this way or if we're just doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Basically what I have done is extended AbstractTokenGranter with new grant_type in which I got authentification from token store and created new TokenRequest with second clientIds. Also you need to create new AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider with your checks and extend UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken to hook it in chain. 
All whats left is to add granter and provider in setup and use your brand new grant_type in request to oauth master server. Good luck!